# How can I replace parenthesis in vim

Tags: regex, vim

In Vim I have:

```
simulación (fig.),pretexto (fig.),excusa (fig.).
```

My goal is:

```
simulación ,pretexto ,excusa .
```

I have tried with: `:%s/\(fig\.\)//g`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Your command looks fine. Does VIM display an error when you run the command?

Comment: I see SO parser hid the slashes when you first submitted the question, no wonder we were confused.

Comment: don't even bather if you're going to have nested parens.  regular expressions can't solve this problem because they have no support for counting (or a stack or recursion).

Comment: Do you really want to keep that misplaced whitespace?  A better goal would be "simulación, pretexto, excusa."

Comment: @Marcin and @ennuikiller:Sorry, it was my fault. I forgot to make a note.
@Svante. Thanks Svante, I have removed the whitespaces, too. But in a second step. It was a long file and sometimes I needed a underscore in place of a whitespace, and sometimes not - because of my task.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Vim doesn't require escaping of brackets by default.  Try:

```
:%s/(fig\.)//g
```

See:

```
:help magic
```

**Edit**

Added backslash escaping of dot.

Comment: Isn't Vim using the content between the escaped parentheses as a group, then throwing it away? It's a significant distinction in that case.

Comment: @Adriano: It is indeed and this wasn't what @Jogusa wanted.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works :-)
Thank you for the second tip, too.

Answer (score 8):

Don't escape the parens - vim by default uses a "magic" escaping scheme.
Try:

```
:%s/(fig\.)//g
```

More info: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/\v

Comment: This will also match (figx) if you don't escape the dot (see my and Adriano's edit: we all did this!).

Answer (score 3):

On Vim 7.2 (WinXP), the command you used only removes 'fig.', but not the parentheses.
Using `%s/(fig\.)//g` gives the intended result.

**Edit** Escaped the dot too, as it matches any character, not just a dot.